# useMemo is calling function every render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having trouble getting useMemo to work in react. Take a look at the very simple react app below:

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";

const testfunc = () => {
  console.log("testfunc");
  return true;
};

function App() {
  const a = useMemo(() => testfunc(), []);

  return <div className="App">My App</div>;
}

export default App;
```

How many times do you think "testfunc" should appear in the console? It should be one but it's coming out as two. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Lets check: do you call `testfunc` in other place? If not, your value memorized. `testfunc` will only called one time when init App component:

Let check my example, just useState to re-render component every 1 second.

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const testfunc = () => {
    console.log("testfunc");
    return true;
};

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState(false);
    const a = useMemo(() => testfunc(), []);
    console.log(a);

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => setState(!state), 1000);
    }, [])

    return <div className="App">My App</div>;
}
```